# Passing Arrays to PHP Extension

Tags: php, arrays, php-extension

I am trying to pass two arrays in PHP to an extension module written in C that has been compiled with the PHP source itself. One of these arrays will be an array of integers and the other will consist of strings. I know PHP and C to a degree, but the Zend engine itself is confusing me quite a bit. I currently can write extensions that PHP can pass non-object and non-array data types to, but I am having a lot of trouble with arrays. Could someone please help?

Ideally, I'd like to have this in a php script:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$arr2 = array("15-01-2010","15-02-2010", "15-03-2010", "15-04-2010", "15-05-2010");
echo myext_myfunction($arr1, $arr2);
```

The return value of my extension's function will be an integer. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at the php documentation
for following functions `zend_hash_num_elements` `zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex` `zend_hash_move_forward_ex`

here is an example of how to loop threw an array `ar`
you can get it in the PARSE_ARGUMENTS via the `z` modifier

```
   HashTable *arr_hash;
   zval **data;
   HashPosition pointer;
   int array_count;
   char * string_key;
   int str_key_len;
   long num_key;
   zval * ar;

    if (ZEND_NUM_ARGS() != 1 || zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "z", &ar)==FAILURE) {
        WRONG_PARAM_COUNT;
    }
    arr_hash = Z_ARRVAL_P(ar);
    array_count = zend_hash_num_elements(arr_hash);
    for(zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex(arr_hash, &pointer); zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(arr_hash, (void**) &data, &pointer) == SUCCESS; zend_hash_move_forward_ex(arr_hash, &pointer)) {
        //convert_to_long(*data); FIXME
        if(Z_TYPE_PP(data) == IS_STRING) {
            //printf("String: %s\n", Z_STRVAL_PP(data));    
        } else if(Z_TYPE_PP(data) == IS_LONG) {
            //printf("Long: %d\n", Z_LVAL_PP(data));    

        }
```

Note for PHP>=7 it looks like (wich is alot easier to handle/read):

```
    HashTable *arr_hash;
    zval **data;
    long num_key;
    zval * val;
    zval * ar;
    zend_string *key;

   ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(1,1)
        Z_PARAM_ZVAL(ar)        
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END(); 


    arr_hash = Z_ARRVAL_P(ar);
    ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_KEY_VAL(arr_hash, num_key, key, val) {
       if(Z_TYPE_P(val) == IS_STRING) {

       } else if(Z_TYPE_P(val) == IS_LONG) {

       }
    } ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_END();
```